# Xaml(WPF) checkbox not reflecting text field content. ivalueprovider conflict

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, web-config

I am creating a form which is having some checkboxes ,
the issue is :
**checkbox** textfield **content** is not appearing on screen while i am setting ivalue provider in webconfig as **LocalFirstValueProvide**, it is showing namespace name , on the other hand the content appears fine with ivalueprovider=**configValueProvide** .

reference images are attaching with query,
Hoping that I can have solution to my problem .

**Code: XAML**

```xml
<controls:CheckBox
    Name="chkStructuredRentalsAvailableatRestructuring" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Grid.Row="4"
    Grid.Column="2"
    IsChecked="{Binding Target.RentalTemplate.STRC_RNTL_ALVB_RSTR_IND, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <controls:TextBlock
        Text="Structured Rentals Available at Restructuring" 
        Name="txtStructuredRentalsAvailableAtRestructuring" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        LineHeight="1"
        Height="Auto"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</controls:CheckBox>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I reproduce your problem? Can you post [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?